# Intersection of Python dictionary and text file

Tags: python, nltk, text-processing

I am completing an NLP exercise and need some help on what would be the best way to get my result. I have two text files, one is a list of words, like a glossary, the other is an article. I need to compute the frequency of each word in my text file list in the input article.

I'm trying to do this step by step so that I improve my skills.

I have already imported the texts, tokenized/split the words in both files, and now I put the words in the article into a dictionary.

My next step is to find the intersection (I'm assuming) of the dictionary and the list-of-words text file and return the frequency of how many word entries exist in my article.

```
wordlist = terms.split()
splittext = input_article.split()
freq = {}
for term in splittext:
    if term in freq:
        freq[term] += 1
    else: freq[term] = 1
#print(freq)

result = {i for i in wordlist if i in freq.keys()}
print(result)
```

This ^ is what I have so far but it's the last line that gets me stuck. I have all the words in my article in a dict... now I want return the frequency of each glossary entry in the input article.

Any tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: how many words do you have in article?

Comment: If you want to see the progress, you should convert your last dict comprehension to normal loop with enumeration, and then every 100 words print information that the program has process 100 words of 50000.

Comment: Better sollution, you should extract keys from both dicts. Convert them to `Set`, then calculate intersection between sets. Then extract occurences of intersection. Should be much much faster

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood this should work:

```
text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"
    
key = "? Lorem Ipsum more was not the with 123 test notin desktop"
    
dict = {}
dict2 = {}
words = text.split(" ")
keys = key.split(" ")
    
for word in words:
    if word in dict:
        dict[word] += 1
    else:
        dict[word] = 1
    
    
for i in range(len(keys)):
    if keys[i] in dict.keys():
        print("Key: {} freq: {}".format(keys[i], dict[keys[i]]))
        dict2[keys[i]] = dict[keys[i]]
        
    
    
print(dict2)
```

Output:

```
{'Lorem': 4, 'Ipsum': 4, 'more': 1, 'was': 1, 'not': 1, 'the': 6, 'with': 2, 'desktop': 1}
```